# Modal popup não funciona

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Codigo do meu panel:

```
<div class="modal">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"   >

        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

Css:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin: auto;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
```

}

Code-behind:

```
Panel1.Visible= true;
```

Mas nada ocorre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste seu caso, o modal deve está dentro do Painel.

Como você tem um ScriptManager na pagina, te aconselho a usar a UpdatePanel para diminuir o fluxo de dados na Aplicação.

Note que o exemplo abaixo, o `UpdatePanel` esta como `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` e `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, para possibilitar um update desta area de forma condicional.

Outro ponto a se notar, é como o btnOpen está fora de um UpdatePanel, é necessario informar o ID do mesmo como Trigger.

**Design**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Scripts>

    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="btnOpen_Click" />    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pModal" runat="server" Visible="false" >
            <div class="modal-bg"></div>
            <div class="modal">
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="btnClose_Click" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOpen" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pModal.Visible = false;
    this.upModal.Update();
}

protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pModal.Visible = true;
    this.upModal.Update();
}
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

.modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: continua sem aparecer nada quando eu chamo: this.pModal.Visible = true;
    this.upModal.Update();

Comment: acredito que esteja relacionado a ordem dos componentes na pagina. tente mover o modal para o final da pagina ou modifique o css do mesmo (z-index: 9999).

Comment: ja coloquei em outras regiões, mas nada. O codigo ta exatamente esse que voce postou.